# Display route layer between current user location and geocoded search locaton in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, routing, geolocation

I would like to create a simple Leaflet app that zooms to the user location, and also to a location defined within the geocode search bar. Secondly, the app should show the shortest route between the two locations, like the way Google Map functions. I have managed to fulfill the first objective and partially the second. However, even though I am following examples as in the [Leaflet Routing Machine app](https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/), the shortest route between the two locations (user and geocoded search) is not being rendered on the map. I know that to simply render a route using the routing.machine plugin is:

```
L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(lat, lon), // User's location
                L.latLng(geocodedLat, geocodedLon) // Geocoded location
            ]
        }).addTo(map);
```

This initially did not work, and [asking ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/c/5e024383-bbfa-473d-a8fa-193a90ef99ff) for solutions to the discrepancy added other `if` statements that in the end, weren't helpful. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <!-- Mobile view -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <!-- Mobile view -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <!-- Leaflet search -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />
    
    <!-- Leaflet routing machine css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css" />

    <!-- Leaflet routing -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./LeafletControlRouteToAddress-master/dist/v1/LeafletControlRoutingtoaddress.css" />

    <!-- Leaflet routing machine -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-routing-machine/3.0.3/leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
    <!-- Leaflet routing machine -->

    <!-- Leaflet routing -->
    
    <!-- Leaflet routing machine js -->
    <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
    <script src="D:\gachuhi\vs_code\geolocation\routing\Leaflet.LocationShare-master\Leaflet.LocationShare.js"></script> -->

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
    <script src="./LeafletControlRouteToAddress-master/dist/v1/LeafletControlRoutingtoaddress.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-routing-machine/3.0.3/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height: 100vh"></div>

    <script>
    
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-1.297221, 36.829702], 11);
    mapLink = "<a href='http://openstreetmap.org'>OpenStreetMap</a>";
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: 'Leaflet &copy; ' + mapLink + ', contribution', maxZoom: 18 }).addTo(map);

    L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);

    map.locate({ setView: true, maxZoom: 16 });

    var lat, lon; // Variables to store user location
    var geocodedLat, geocodedLon; // Variables to store geocoded location

    function onLocationFound(e) {
        lat = e.latlng.lat;
        lon = e.latlng.lng;

        var radius = e.accuracy;
        L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();
        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);

        // Create a routing control after obtaining both locations
        if (geocodedLat !== undefined && geocodedLon !== undefined) {
            createRoutingControl();
        }
    }

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    
    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    map.on('geocoded', function(e) {
        geocodedLat = e.latlng.lat;
        geocodedLon = e.latlng.lng;

        // Create a routing control after obtaining both locations
        if (lat !== undefined && lon !== undefined) {
            createRoutingControl();
        }
    });
    
    function createRoutingControl() {
        L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(lat, lon), // User's location
                L.latLng(geocodedLat, geocodedLon) // Geocoded location
            ]
        }).addTo(map);
    }

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

How can I display the shortest route layer on my map?

Answer (score 0):

- To catch geocoder event when location is found you can use `markgeocode` geocoder control event.
- To prevent default geocoder action you can use `defaultMarkGeocode: false` option.
- To zoom on route found by router you can use `fitSelectedRoutes: true` router control option.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
var lat, lon;
var geocodedLat, geocodedLon;

var geocoderControl = L.Control.geocoder({
  defaultMarkGeocode: false
}).addTo(map);

geocoderControl.on('markgeocode', function(e) {
  geocodedLat = e.geocode.center.lat;
  geocodedLon = e.geocode.center.lng;

  if (lat !== undefined && lon !== undefined) {
    createRoutingControl();
  }
});

map.locate({ setView: true, maxZoom: 16 });

function onLocationFound(e) {
  lat = e.latlng.lat;
  lon = e.latlng.lng;

  var radius = e.accuracy;
  L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();
  L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);

  if (geocodedLat !== undefined && geocodedLon !== undefined) {
    createRoutingControl();
  }
}

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

function onLocationError(e) {
  alert(e.message);
}

map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

function createRoutingControl() {
  L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
      L.latLng(lat, lon), // User's location
      L.latLng(geocodedLat, geocodedLon) // Geocoded location
    ],
    fitSelectedRoutes: true
  }).addTo(map);
}
```